# KineticJS: Saving to JSON: Objects saved more than once

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas, kineticjs

**big edit**

Having analyzed my situation, it seems to be another question / another scenario, more generally about saving to json.

So, I add a new Shapegroup to a layer on my stage with the following code:

```
...
var selectedShape, json = null;
...
function addNode(xPos, yPos)
{
    //create the new node
    var node = new Kinetic.Circle({
        id: 'myRect',
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos,
        radius: 30,
        fill: '#FFFFFF',
        stroke: '#000000',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        // test: "testattr"
    });

    // create the label
    var label = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: node.getX() - node.getRadius() + 10,
        y: node.getY() + node.getRadius() + 4,
        text: 'node',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fill: 'black',
    });

    // create group
    var nodeGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        draggable: true
    });

    // add shapes to group
    nodeGroup.add(node);
    nodeGroup.add(label);

    // add group to the layer
    layer.add(nodeGroup);

    // add layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);


    /*
    *  Events for Nodes
    *  all events for the actual states / nodes
    */

    // mouse over => red stroke
    node.on('mouseover', function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        this.setStroke('red');
        layer.draw();
    });
    // mouse out => back in black
    node.on('mouseout', function() {
        if(selectedShape != this){
            console.log('mouseout fired, Position: ' + node.getX());
            $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
            this.setStroke('#000000');
            writeMessage(messageLayer, node.getX()); // just for testing purposes
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    node.on('click tap', function(){ //relevant
        if(selectedShape != null){
            $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
            selectedShape.setStroke('#000000');
            layer.draw();
        }
        selectedShape = null;
        console.log('clicked');
        selectedShape = this;
        this.setStroke('red');
        layer.draw();
    });

    /*
    *  Events for Node-labels
    *  events for labels
    */
    label.on('mouseover', function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'text');
        this.setStroke('red');
        this.setStrokeWidth(0.5)
        layer.draw();
    });

    label.on('mouseout', function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
        this.setStroke('');
        this.setStrokeWidth(0);
        layer.draw();
    });

    //change the Label of a node, return 'node' if nothing entered or cancelled.
    label.on('click', function(){
        var lblTxt = prompt('Neue Bezeichnung:', ''); 
        if (lblTxt) {
            this.setText(lblTxt);
        } else {
            this.setText('node');
        }
        layer.draw();
    });
}
```

Having a button 'add new State' which actually adds a new group.
Code:

```
$('#createNode').click(function(e){
        addNode(125, 125);
    });
```

And a Button "remove State" which removes a selected nodegroup.
Code:

```
$('#removeNode').click(function(e){
        if(selectedShape){
        var selectedGroup = selectedShape.getParent();
        selectedGroup.removeChildren();
        selectedGroup.remove();
        layer.draw();
        } else {
            writeMessage(messageLayer, 'No Object chosen');
        }
    });
```

Also, there's a button 'save to json' where I want to save all the actually remaining Shapes on my Stage.
Code:

```
        $('#saveJSON').click(function(e){
         json = null;
        json = stage.toJSON();
        console.log(json);
    });
```

So, now I test the following cases:

**Case 1**: Save empty stage

JSON output:

```
{
"attrs": {
    "width": 960,
    "height": 600
},
"className": "Stage",
"children": [
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

}

Status: Seems to be OK.*So, the formatting issue with the last } depends on stackoverflow, it should (and is) actually be included to code tag.*

**Case 2**: Add one Node after Saving empty Stage (double-clicking / tapping or using button is no difference here). Save again.

JSON Output:

```
{
"attrs": {
    "width": 960,
    "height": 600
},
"className": "Stage",
"children": [
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": [
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "#000000",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Status: Why is there an empty Layer? But: One Group, two Objects, seems to be okay.

**Case 3**

Adding another Node. Save.

JSON Output:

```
{
"attrs": {
    "width": 960,
    "height": 600
},
"className": "Stage",
"children": [
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": [
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "#000000",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true,
                    "x": 206,
                    "y": 75,
                    "rotation": 0,
                    "scaleX": 1,
                    "scaleY": 1,
                    "offsetX": 0,
                    "offsetY": 0,
                    "skewX": 0,
                    "skewY": 0
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "red",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": [
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "#000000",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true,
                    "x": 206,
                    "y": 75,
                    "rotation": 0,
                    "scaleX": 1,
                    "scaleY": 1,
                    "offsetX": 0,
                    "offsetY": 0,
                    "skewX": 0,
                    "skewY": 0
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "red",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Status: Here you can see the first occurence of my problem: All the objects on my stage are doubled in my JSON file on two different layers. So they are tripled and so on when adding more objects. My Problem: I want to add a data model and use the data with a database, so I think this is pretty messy but I have no clue where I went wrong.

** case 4**
Removing all but one node from my stage:

JSON Output:

```
{
"attrs": {
    "width": 960,
    "height": 600
},
"className": "Stage",
"children": [
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": [
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "#000000",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": [
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "draggable": true
                },
                "className": "Group",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "id": "myRect",
                            "x": 125,
                            "y": 125,
                            "radius": 30,
                            "fill": "#FFFFFF",
                            "stroke": "#000000",
                            "strokeWidth": 4,
                            "test": "testattr"
                        },
                        "className": "Circle"
                    },
                    {
                        "attrs": {
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "x": 105,
                            "y": 159,
                            "text": "node",
                            "fontSize": 12,
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fill": "black"
                        },
                        "className": "Text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Status: Again, the remaining nodes are doubled.

** case 5**: Removing all nodes, having an empty stage again (after adding 2 nodes, then removing them)

JSON Output:

```
{
"attrs": {
    "width": 960,
    "height": 600
},
"className": "Stage",
"children": [
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "className": "Layer",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

}

Status: Stage is empty, but layers still remaining. Not that nice.

**Conclusion**: I think I'm doing something pretty wrong. It's a lot of JSON in this question and I hope someone actually reads through this and may help me figuring out what I did wrong. Would be so great.

Best regards,
Dominik

**another edit**
Problem seems for me in addnode-function, using stage.add(layer); to add new shapegroups. A different way to add new groups to *one* layer would be much appreciated for I am fairly new to kineticjs and don't know it yet.

Comment: could you include the toJSON string in the question and show what exactly is happening there

Comment: @Ani just edited my whole question, because it generally had nothing to do with my remove-mechanism. I hope now it gets somewhat clearer, although now there is a lot of JSON ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after writing out this Question, rewriting the whole question, adding another edit after further investigaten, I actually found my problem and I think I want to share it with you:

At the addnode-function, i called `stage.add(layer)` - as the code says, it adds a new layer for each new Shapegroup. This caused the behaviour I explained in the question.

Now I removed `stage.add(layer)` from addNode to my `init()`-function which is  only called at startup. At addNode, I now just say `layer.add(nodeGroup); layer.draw()`; and it works like a charm now. Sorry for the inconvenience :( I had a knot in my brain.

Comment: this just saved my life, I had the same thing happen and I didn't know how to fix it!